# HDR photos on iPhone 3GS with iOS4.1

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, hdr

I've just installed iOS 4.1 on my iPhone 3GS, and want to try the new HDR feature in the Camera App... But it doesn't seem to be available.

Is it possible to use it in the 3GS? Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, the [HDR feature added in iOS 4.1](http://www.apple.com/iphone/software-update/) only works on iPhone 4.

> Take great photos that capture a wider range of light intensity using the new high dynamic range (HDR) setting **on iPhone 4**, which automatically combines multiple exposures into a single HDR image.

If you want to take HDR photos on your 3GS, there's an app for that: [Pro HDR](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pro-hdr/id347104281?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

The HDR feature is for the iPhone 4 only. I believe it requires the higher-quality camera of that version.